"Traceback (most recent call last):" how to remove this error in python?
I am making a voice assistant in Python. I just create its first function but I am having same traceback error again and again. can anyone tell me what mistake I am making here?
this is what i created yet:
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition
import pyaudio

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 170)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takecommand():
    r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.energy_threshold = 300
        audio = r.listen(source, 0, 4)

    try:
        print("understanding")
        query = r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, language="en-pk")
        print(f"u said{query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("say that again")
        return "none"
    return query

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takecommand().lower()
        if "wake up" in query:
            from greetme import greetMe

            greetMe()

            while True:
                query = takecommand().lower()
                if "go to sleep" in query:
                    speak("Ok sir, you can call me anytime")
                    break


but I
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\onean\PycharmProjects\jarvis\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    query = takecommand().lower()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\onean\PycharmProjects\jarvis\main.py", line 19, in takecommand
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\onean\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\onean\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

i am having this error again and again I couldn't find any error in my code. i am learning python so i don't have that much knowledge about this error

"Traceback" is not the error. "No module named 'distutils'" is the error. A traceback is just how Python tells you where an error happened, it's not a particular kind of error.

Try input this command:
pip install setuptools distutils-pytest


hey man, thanks for helping me solve this error.i input this command the error is gone when i run the program but it's not listening to my voice or anything and when i stop the program it gives me the same traceback error. if u know anything about it plz let me know

hello, @muteeb. I'm glad I helped you. Unfortunately, my Linux machine requires heavy dependencies (700 MB), so I can't install them. Could you, please, update your question with the error you face?
